# Migrating global BroadcastReceivers to LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android

I am migrating some `BroadcastReceiver`s defined in the Manifest to `LocalBroadcastManager`.

These `BroadcastReceiver`s don't need to be called from other apps. 
They are called through `sendBroadcast()` either from `Activity`s in response to UI actions, or from a utility class that executes HTTP requests and delivers the responses in the `Intent`.

I found out about `LocalBroadcastManager` only recently and want to optimize my code. I haven't made any benchmarks (and I'm not sure how). Is it worth doing or is it premature optimization? The `BroadcastReceiver`s are called in response to user actions so the migration might not be worth it.

Where should the `registerReceiver` registration be done? Is the `Application` the correct place?

Comment: Can you provide a use case for this? The primary reasons for having a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest -- so third-party code can invoke them via a particular broadcast action or via a `PendingIntent` -- have no meaning with `LocalBroadcastManager`. If you could explain why you have local-only "global `BroadcastReceivers`" in the first place, it might help us provide you better advice.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have updated the question - I simply didn't know about `LocalBroadcastManager` when the old code was written.

Comment: The two sentences that you added, while nice, do not provide a use case and do not explain why you have local-only "global `BroadcastReceivers`" in the first place, as I suggested in my initial comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. I hope this last edit gives some more context to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where should the registerReceiver registration be done?

They should be registered by whatever component is responsible for their work.

Principally, `LocalBroadcastManager` is used for inter-component communication. The quintessential example is an `IntentService` sending a local broadcast `Intent` to let any interested activities know that something changed... if and only if there is such an activity in the foreground. In that scenario, the activities would register a receiver in `onResume()` and unregister that receiver in `onPause()`.

So, let's look at your two lightly-described "use cases":

> from Activitys in response to UI actions

Delete the `sendBroadcast()`. Delete the `BroadcastReceiver`. Just do the work here, or fork an `AsyncTask` to do the work, or send a command to an `IntentService` do to the work via `startService()`.

> from a utility class that executes HTTP requests and delivers the responses in the Intent.

Either this "utility class" is being use by an activity (via an `AsyncTask`), an `IntentService`, or neither.

If the utility class is being used by an `AsyncTask` from an activity, dump the `sendBroadcast()`, dump the `BroadcastReceiver`, and simply do the work in the `AsyncTask` and/or activity.

If the utility class is being used by an `IntentService`, and you are trying to update the UI based upon that work, that's the pattern I outlined in my second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: a good example is when you are using a tabhost and want interchild event management

Comment: @L7ColWinters: Putting activities in tabs was a lousy solution to begin with and, fortunately, is now officially deprecated.